# В чем хранить информацию?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net, файлы, база-данных

Если есть задача реализовать оконное приложение, которое позволяет заносить некую инфу, например курс евро(по дате) и потом эту же инфу выводить в программе, то в чем удобнее хранить эту информацию? 
Не создавать же базу данных ради одной таблички. Возможно ли хранить информацию в текстовых файлах, или так не делается?

Comment: Зависит от объемов, от сложности структуры данных.
Небольшие простенькие объемы можно тупо текстом, можно покрасивше в xml.

Comment: `XML / JSON / ProtocolBuffers`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать двоичную сериализацию с помощью класса BinaryFormatter. При этом нужно помечать классы объекты которых будут сериализироваться, атрибутом [Serializable]. В таком случае информация будет не читабельной для пользователей и компактной по размеру. Если нужна читабельность, как уже подсказали - можна использовать XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 3):

Можно ещё использовать БД, не требующие установки сервера, такие как `Sql Server CE` или `SQLite`. Я работал с `SQLite` - там просто `dll` надо к проекту подцепить.